# excluding current post from get_posts

Tags: get-posts

i have this block of code displayed in single.php template

```
<ul class="cat-wrap">
    <?php 
        global $post;
        $categories = get_the_category();
        foreach ($categories as $category) :
    ?>
    <h5>same from <?php echo $category->name; ?></h5>
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'numberposts' => 5,
            'category' => $category->term_id,
            'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )
            );
        $posts = get_posts($args);
        foreach($posts as $post) :
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
   <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->term_id);?>" title="View all posts filed under <?php echo $category->name; ?>">جميع مقالات قسم <?php echo $category->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
```

the loop is working fine except `'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )` behaving in a weird way . to explain more if i have a post that share 4 different categories . the generated code is the following

```
<ul>
<h5>same from Cat1</h5>
<li>another article 1</li>
<li>another article 2</li>
<li>another article 3</li>
<li>another article 4</li>

<h5>same from Cat2</h5>
<li>Current Article</li>
<li>another article 1</li>
<li>another article 2</li>
<li>another article 3</li>

<h5>same from Cat3</h5>
<li>Current Article</li>
<li>another article 1</li>
<li>another article 2</li>
<li>another article 3</li>

<h5>same from Cat4</h5>
<li>Current Article</li>
<li>another article 1</li>
<li>another article 2</li>
<li>another article 3</li>
```

like you can notice only `<h5>same from Cat1</h5>` that excluding the current post , the rest including it and excluding some other random post.

thanks in advance and i hope i managed to explained my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite the value of `$post` when you output the first set of posts, so it's no longer the same post object as your single post.

You can either `wp_reset_postdata()` after each loop (which you should do after the last one anyway), or assign `$post->ID` to some other var before the loop, and reference that instead so it doesn't get overwritten.

Comment: assign `$post->ID` to a variable worked great , but if you do not mind can you explain to me why exactly i need to put `wp_reset_postdata()` after the last loop any way.

Comment: any template tags or code after that loop that expects to be operating on the original post object will produce incorrect results, because it will contain the wrong post. it's just good practice to always clean up after running secondary queries.